# 500 Internal Server while passing List of objects via jquery.post to wcf method

Tags: jquery, wcf

I want to post a list of object to my `WCF` method through `jquery.post`. My other methods are working fine. But one method that insert data into database table and accept data as generic list is giving internal server error. Although I have tested this insert method with my `consoletest` client and it is also working fine. But only getting problem with jQuery post. Might be my JSON object is not in required format.

Below is my code sample

```
WCF method:

    [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
        bool InsertTransaction(ListOfTransactions listOfTransaction);

    [DataContract]
    public class ListOfTransactions {
        [DataMember]
       public List<Trasactions> trasactions { get; set; }
    }
    [DataContract]
    public class Trasactions
    {
        [DataMember]
        ///......properties goes here
    }
```

jQuery Code:

```
    var Url = "service uri ";
            var method = "InsertTransaction";
            var trasactions = { "listOfTransaction": [ 
            { 
                "ShopUID": 1,                
                "Clientuid": 1
            },
             { 
                "ShopUID": 1,                
                "Clientuid": 2
            },
            ]};
            //$.post(Url + '/' + method, JSON.stringify(data), function (e) { alert("successed") });
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "service uri /InsertTransaction/",
                data: JSON.stringify(trasactions),
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                processData: true,
                success: function (data, status, jqXHR) {
                    alert("success..." + data);
                },
                error: function (xhr) {
                    alert(xhr.responseText);
                }
            });
```

But I am getting an Internal server 500 error. Below is my `web.config`. All other service contract methods are working fine so I think there is no issue in my config file. but I am not getting full error info even I have set `includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"`.

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <configuration>
    <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" />
    <authentication mode="None"></authentication>    
    </system.web>
    <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false and remove       the     metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="WebBehavior">
          <enableWebScript/>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>

    <standardEndpoints>
      <webScriptEndpoint>
        <standardEndpoint name="" crossDomainScriptAccessEnabled="true" />
      </webScriptEndpoint>
    </standardEndpoints>
    <services>
      <service name="POS_Service.PosService">
        <endpoint address=""  binding="basicHttpBinding"                   contract="POS_Service.IPosService"></endpoint>
        <endpoint address="Web" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="POS_Service.IPosService" behaviorConfiguration="WebBehavior"></endpoint>
      </service>
    </services>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
    <httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type" />
      </customHeaders>
      </httpProtocol>
     </system.webServer>
     </configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

Jquery Post on cross domain is not possible. 
Change the wcf method like below

```
[OperationContract]
    [WebGet(RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    bool InsertTransaction(string listOfTransaction);


Pass the json data as string and desrialize the Json data at server side.
change the datatype to "JSONP"



$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "service uri /InsertTransaction/",
            data: trasactions,
           **dataType: "jsonp",**
            processData: true,
            success: function (data, status, jqXHR) {
                alert("success..." + data);
            },
            error: function (xhr) {
                alert(xhr.responseText);
            }
        });
```